# Custom resource name as variable

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In chef you can call a recipe by using string variables like

`cookbook='my_cookbook'
%w[ recipe1 recipe2 recipe3 ].each do |recipe|
   include_recipe "#{cookbook}::#{recipe}"
end`

Is it possible to do a similar thing to execute different custom resources?

Comment: can u explain what is this `include_recipe "#{cookbook}::#{recipe}"` referring too? is it a `Class` or `Instance`.

Comment: I am going to assume you are looking for `load` (as this appears to be what `include_recipe` actually does only with a bit of require type logic e.g. do not reload if already loaded) that being said you would need to strictly adhere to a specific file structure to work appropriately because you must be able to infer the file path from the class name. which is what `"#{cookbook}::#{recipe}"` is specifying. Otherwise how you want to go about this or why is extremely unclear from this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably wouldn't actually use a loop for this but:

```
%w{one two three}.each do |res|
  declare_resource(:"mycookbook_#{res}", "nameofresource") do
     # Normal resource body block goes here.
  end
end
```

If you can be more specific about the use case, I can try to give you a better example of what to actually use instead.

Comment: thanks! this is what i was looking for. the loop was for illustrating using variables.